# How to indicate that I want the interval with the lowest value among all the intervals that satisfy a condition

Tags: r

I have `df1` that summarises different datetimes. I also have `df2` that summarises water temperature at different depths over time. I want to add a column in `df1` called `Term_depth`showing the mean depth between TWO CONSECUTIVE depths for a specific datetime IF THERE'S a difference bigger than `4.5`. My problem is that sometimes for a specific datetime in `df1`, there are two intervals in `df2` for this specific datetime that satisfy they are bigger than `4.5`. In these situations, I want the mean depth for the interval that has the lowest temperature at the highest depth. That is, if `df2$T15` is 25, `df2$T25` is 17 and `df2$T35` is 24, I'm interested in the mean of the interval `df2$T15`- `df2$T25`, since has in its lower level a value smaller than the interval `df2$25`-`df2$35`.

As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 08:01:17","2016-08-01 09:17:14","2016-08-01 10:29:31","2016-08-01 11:19:02","2016-08-01 12:22:45","2016-08-01 13:19:27","2016-08-01 14:58:17","2016-08-01 15:29:10","2016-08-01 16:27:13"))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")
df1$Round_datetime<- round_date(df1$DateTime, unit = "hour")

df2<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 07:00:00","2016-08-01 08:00:00","2016-08-01 09:00:00","2016-08-01 10:00:00","2016-08-01 11:00:00","2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 13:00:00","2016-08-01 14:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 16:00:00","2016-08-01 17:00:00"),T5=c(27.8,27.0,27.5,27.1,27.0,26.8,26.3,26.0,26.3,27.1,26.7),
T15=c(24.2,22.0,23.4,23.1,22.7,22.5,21.5,22.0,22.3,24.4,25.4),T25=c(19.5,21.0,20.0,19.5,19.6,16.0,16.3,16.2,16.7,16.4,23.1),T35=c(17.3,16.0,16.0,16.5,16.7,16.3,16.7,16.9,16.7,21.4,18.2))
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")

df1
             DateTime      Round_datetime
1 2016-08-01 08:01:17 2016-08-01 08:00:00
2 2016-08-01 09:17:14 2016-08-01 09:00:00
3 2016-08-01 10:29:31 2016-08-01 10:00:00
4 2016-08-01 11:19:02 2016-08-01 11:00:00
5 2016-08-01 12:22:45 2016-08-01 12:00:00
6 2016-08-01 13:19:27 2016-08-01 13:00:00
7 2016-08-01 14:58:17 2016-08-01 15:00:00
8 2016-08-01 15:29:10 2016-08-01 15:00:00
9 2016-08-01 16:27:13 2016-08-01 16:00:00

df2
              DateTime   T5  T15  T25  T35
1  2016-08-01 07:00:00 27.8 24.2 19.5 17.3 # One interval bigger than `4.5`
2  2016-08-01 08:00:00 27.0 22.0 21.0 16.0 # Two intervals bigger than `4.5`
3  2016-08-01 09:00:00 27.5 23.4 20.0 16.0 # Zero intervals bigger than `4.5`
4  2016-08-01 10:00:00 27.1 23.1 19.5 16.5 # Zero intervals bigger than `4.5`
5  2016-08-01 11:00:00 27.0 22.7 20.6 15.7 # One interval bigger than `4.5`
6  2016-08-01 12:00:00 26.8 22.5 16.0 16.3 # One interval bigger than `4.5`
7  2016-08-01 13:00:00 26.3 21.5 16.3 21.6 # Three intervals bigger than `4.5`.
8  2016-08-01 14:00:00 26.0 22.0 16.2 16.9 # One interval bigger than `4.5`
9  2016-08-01 15:00:00 26.3 22.3 16.7 16.7 # One interval bigger than `4.5`
10 2016-08-01 16:00:00 27.1 24.4 16.4 21.4 # Two intervals bigger than 4.5
11 2016-08-01 17:00:00 26.7 25.4 23.1 18.2 # One interval bigger than `4.5`
```

I would like to get:

```
df1
             DateTime      Round_datetime Term_depth
1 2016-08-01 08:01:17 2016-08-01 08:00:00         30
2 2016-08-01 09:17:14 2016-08-01 09:00:00         NA
3 2016-08-01 10:29:31 2016-08-01 10:00:00         NA
4 2016-08-01 11:19:02 2016-08-01 11:00:00         NA
5 2016-08-01 12:22:45 2016-08-01 12:00:00         20
6 2016-08-01 13:19:27 2016-08-01 13:00:00         20
7 2016-08-01 14:58:17 2016-08-01 15:00:00         20
8 2016-08-01 15:29:10 2016-08-01 15:00:00         20
9 2016-08-01 16:27:13 2016-08-01 16:00:00         20
```

How can I do it?

I tried a for loop. The problem with it is that it takes the deepest interval by default. For instance, `df1$Term_depth[6]` or `df1$Term_depth[9]` are assigned as `30` instead of `20`.

Here you have the code and the result with the for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {

    if(abs(df2$T35[which(df1$Round_datetime[i] == df2$DateTime)] - df2$T25[which(df1$Round_datetime[i] == df2$DateTime)]) > 4.5){
      df1$Term_Depth[i] <- 30
    }else if (abs(df2$T25[which(df1$Round_datetime[i] == df2$DateTime)] - df2$T15[which(df1$Round_datetime[i] == df2$DateTime)]) > 4.5){
      df1$Term_Depth[i] <- 20
    }else if (abs(df2$T15[which(df1$Round_datetime[i] == df2$DateTime)] - df2$T5[which(df1$Round_datetime[i] == df2$DateTime)]) > 4.5){
      df1$Term_Depth[i] <- 10
    }else{
      df1$Term_Depth[i] <- "NA"
    }
  }

df1
             DateTime      Round_datetime Term_Depth
1 2016-08-01 08:01:17 2016-08-01 08:00:00         30
2 2016-08-01 09:17:14 2016-08-01 09:00:00         NA
3 2016-08-01 10:29:31 2016-08-01 10:00:00         NA
4 2016-08-01 11:19:02 2016-08-01 11:00:00         NA
5 2016-08-01 12:22:45 2016-08-01 12:00:00         20
6 2016-08-01 13:19:27 2016-08-01 13:00:00         30 # Should be 20
7 2016-08-01 14:58:17 2016-08-01 15:00:00         20
8 2016-08-01 15:29:10 2016-08-01 15:00:00         20
9 2016-08-01 16:27:13 2016-08-01 16:00:00         30 # Should be 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#As function round_date was not found by default I round it here
df1$Round_datetime <- lubridate::round_date(df1$DateTime, unit = "hour")

df1$Term_depth <- as.numeric(apply(df2[,2:5], 1, function(x) { #Take per row
  tt <- which(abs(diff(x))>4.5)  #find where difference bigger than 4.5
  tt[which.min(x[1+tt])]*10  #Take where lowest temperature at the highest depth
}))[match(df1$Round_datetime, df2$DateTime)] #Merge df2 to df1

#             DateTime Term_depth
#1 2016-08-01 08:01:17         30
#2 2016-08-01 09:17:14         NA
#3 2016-08-01 10:29:31         NA
#4 2016-08-01 11:19:02         NA
#5 2016-08-01 12:22:45         20
#6 2016-08-01 13:19:27         20
#7 2016-08-01 14:58:17         20
#8 2016-08-01 15:29:10         20
#9 2016-08-01 16:27:13         20
```

Comment: Thanks, user10488504. One of the problems with your result compared with my expected one is that in df1, I made a mistake and I wrote as datetime "2016-08-01 11:35:02" instead of "2016-08-01 11:19:02" in `df1$DateTime[4]` and also "2016-08-01 15:30:10" instead of "2016-08-01 15:29:10" in df1$DateTime[8]. I changed those datetimes because I wanted these rows to behave according to different rows from df2. I guess that if you load again df1 according to my script, now in your result the rows 4 and 8 will appear as I was expecting. The problem comes with row 9, where I would like that appears 20

Comment: In row 9 I am interested in `20` instead of 30 because it is at 20 meters depth where the temperature reaches the lowest temperature. In the interval T25-T35 the temperature increase and goes from 16.4 to 21.4

Comment: Line 10 of df2 is created currently as: >2016-08-01 16:00:00 27.1 26.4 21.4 16.4< but in the question it shows >2016-08-01 16:00:00 27.1 24.4 16.4 21.4< what explains why you get 30m but expect 20m.

Comment: You are right. I changed it. I used your code and it works perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one interval > 4.5, but you always want the highest of the two intervals, then you can use a nested ifelse to 'move down through the depths' until the > 4.5 criterion is met, and it doesn't matter if there are subsequent intervals at lower depths. (If I understand the problem correctly). Create this variable in your df2, then merge with df1 to associate the correct interval with the correct time.

```
df2$Term_depth <- ifelse(abs(df2$T5-df2$T15) > 4.5, 10,
                   ifelse(abs(df2$T15-df2$T25) > 4.5 ,20,
                     ifelse(abs(df2$T25-df2$T35) > 4.5 ,30,NA)))

df1 <- merge(x = df1 , y = df2[,c("DateTime","Term_depth")], by.x = "Round_datetime" , by.y = "DateTime" , all.x = TRUE)

df1

> df1
       Round_datetime            DateTime Term_depth
1 2016-08-01 08:00:00 2016-08-01 08:01:17         10
2 2016-08-01 09:00:00 2016-08-01 09:17:14         NA
3 2016-08-01 10:00:00 2016-08-01 10:29:31         NA
4 2016-08-01 12:00:00 2016-08-01 11:35:02         20
5 2016-08-01 12:00:00 2016-08-01 12:22:45         20
6 2016-08-01 13:00:00 2016-08-01 13:19:27         10
7 2016-08-01 15:00:00 2016-08-01 14:58:17         20
8 2016-08-01 16:00:00 2016-08-01 15:30:10         20
9 2016-08-01 16:00:00 2016-08-01 16:27:13         20
```

My output is slightly different to your desired output, but as I understood your 4.5 intervals, your #comments on each line didn't fully match. Either way maybe this code will provide a solution?

Comment: Thanks Roasty247!! I am interested in the interval that the temperature reaches the lowest temperature. For instance, in row 1 in df1, water temperature moves from 27.0 to 22.0 from 5 to 15 m, but also later the temperature move from 21.0 to 16.0 from 25 to 35 m. In this case, I am interested in the last interval since it is the one that reaches the lowest temperature. I also made some mistakes writing the code. Now I think it is correct. The only problem with your code is that It takes the shallower interval with a change in water temperature bigger than 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

My solution below assumes that you want the interval with the lower temperature.

As these are row-by-row operations, you can vectorize it - no need for loops.

```
# First create three dummy variables with TRUE if an interval is > 4.5
df2$int1 <- df2$T5-df2$T15  > 4.5
df2$int2 <- df2$T15-df2$T25 > 4.5
df2$int3 <- df2$T25-df2$T35 > 4.5

# Then for each pair of intervals where both are TRUE check which has the lower temperature
# (you could probably wrap it up)
# First for T5-T15 vs T15-T25
df2[df2$int1 == TRUE & df2$int2 == TRUE & df2$T15 < df2$T25, "int2"]  <- FALSE
df2[df2$int1 == TRUE & df2$int2 == TRUE & df2$T15 >= df2$T25, "int1"] <- FALSE

# Same for T15-T25 vs T25-T35
df2[df2$int2 == TRUE & df2$int3 == TRUE & df2$T25 < df2$T35, "int3"]  <- FALSE
df2[df2$int2 == TRUE & df2$int3 == TRUE & df2$T25 >= df2$T35, "int2"] <- FALSE

# Same for T5-T15 vs T25-T35
df2[df2$int1 == TRUE & df2$int3 == TRUE & df2$T15 < df2$T35, "int3"]  <- FALSE
df2[df2$int1 == TRUE & df2$int3 == TRUE & df2$T15 >= df2$T35, "int1"] <- FALSE

# Now we have only one TRUE value in each row - we can get the mean depth by matrix multiplication
df2$Term_depth <- as.matrix(df2[, c("int1", "int2", "int3")]) %*% c(10, 20, 30)
df2[df2$Term_depth == 0, "Term_depth"] <- NA

# Merge it to df1
merge(df1, df2[, c("DateTime", "Term_depth")], by.x = "Round_datetime", by.y = "DateTime", all.x = TRUE)

       Round_datetime            DateTime Term_depth
1 2016-08-01 08:00:00 2016-08-01 08:01:17         30
2 2016-08-01 09:00:00 2016-08-01 09:17:14         NA
3 2016-08-01 10:00:00 2016-08-01 10:29:31         NA
4 2016-08-01 12:00:00 2016-08-01 11:35:02         20
5 2016-08-01 12:00:00 2016-08-01 12:22:45         20
6 2016-08-01 13:00:00 2016-08-01 13:19:27         20
7 2016-08-01 15:00:00 2016-08-01 14:58:17         20
8 2016-08-01 16:00:00 2016-08-01 15:30:10         30
9 2016-08-01 16:00:00 2016-08-01 16:27:13         30
```

Output is not the same as yours because the input you provided was also simply different from the printed `data.frame`s.

Comment: Thanks MRau. I changed the mistakes in my post, since I had several. Your code works perfectly :)